# Fail to create DockerFile - copy error, project not found

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-core, dockerfile

Fail to create DockerFile (Linux target) which was generated automatically using VS2019 -> add docker support,
my project structure is:
D:\MasterProjects\WebApi\WebApi\WebApi.csproj
D:\MasterProjects\Proj1\Proj1\Proj1.vbproj
D:\MasterProjects\Proj1\Proj2\Proj2.vbproj

In the WebApi project, there is a reference to Proj1
In the Proj1 project, there is a reference to Proj2

I've tried to add also a copy section to the third project (Proj2) without any luck,
tried also to run the docker file from the sln folder (changing the copy path), also no luck
my docker file located in D:\MasterProjects\WebApi\WebApi
I get a copy error on the second project which can't be found
the docker file content is:

`````
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
COPY ["../Proj1/Proj1/Proj1.vbproj", "../Proj1/Proj1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApi/WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]````
`````

Comment: 'Fail to create DockerFile' --- is this a error when creating project from template?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? the docker file code you shared does not have anything to copy proj2...

Comment: @LeiYang

the error occurs when running the docker build -t [myDockerproject]/someName .

 => ERROR [build 4/8] COPY [../Proj1/Proj1/Proj1.vbproj, ../Proj1/Proj1/]             

 failed to compute cache key: "/Proj1/Proj1/Proj1.vbproj" not found: not found`

Comment: often you should **cd** to project dir, then docker build.

Comment: then I should use the -f switch in order to specify the DockerFile location. already tried to do it yesterday but no luck.

Comment: cd to where you have dockerfile.

Comment: Is the Dockerfile located a the solution folder, or in WebApi folder? From where do you run the `docker build` command?

Comment: No,the Dockerfile located in :MasterProjects\WebApi\WebApi